# Applescript iterate over elements of HTML page

Tags: javascript, applescript

I'm currently trying to iterate over a bunch of links on a webpage such that my applescript code will click on each one after the page loads. I can click on one of the links, but I don't know how to grab all of the elements and then iterate over them one by one. Here is my current code:

```
tell application "Safari"

    set theScript to "document.getElementsByClassName('thread_bump')[0].click();"
    do JavaScript theScript in current tab of first window

end tell
```

The above code clicks the first instance of the element who's class name is "thread_bump," but I want to click on all of the elements with that class name, not just the first.

So, is there a way to get all of the elements and then iterate over them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set theScript to "var bumps = document.getElementsByClassName('thread_bump'); for(var i=0;i<bumps.length; i++) bumps[i].click();"
    do JavaScript theScript in current tab of first window
end tell
```

getElementsByClassName is returning an array of elements, so you just iterate that.

Comment: Oof. Too easy! I've been using too many different languages as of late. Thanks for the quick response!